# Bokeh and Django: Bokeh to retrieve only data of an authenticated Django user

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, bokeh

Since I have not found a clear way to integrate an interactive Bokeh app within Django, I am trying to make a Bokeh app and Django backend talk to each other via API.

So the Bokeh app is running on its own server and is only querying the API for data. Next, the Bokeh app is displayed in an `iframe` within Django template.

Thing is the Bokeh app should retrieve data only for the currently logged in user. But the Bokeh app knows nothing about current user, since it is basically only an interactive chart fed with data from API, and the whole authentication is done on Django's side, on separate server.

Is there any way to solve this?

For reference, this is my API view:

```
class ListActivitiesView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ActivitySerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        # this is where Bokeh gets lost:
        return Activity.objects.filter(athlete__username=user)
```

Comment: Take a look at this : https://www.hackerearth.com/fr/practice/notes/bokeh-interactive-visualization-library-use-graph-with-django-template/ . It shows how to embed bokeh with django without using another server

Comment: Yes, but this will work only for static plots. Interactive plots - with Javascript underneath - require Bokeh server.